# Strange issue with Mockito and Spring test MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, mockito, spring-test-mvc

I am unit testing the **following Spring MVC controller method**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/advertisement/family/edit/{advertisementId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
@AdvertisementExistsAndBelongsToMemberCheck
public String editFamilyAdvertisementForm(@ModelAttribute FamilyAdvertisementInfo familyAdvertisementInfo, @PathVariable long advertisementId, Model model, @CurrentMember Member member) {
    FamilyAdvertisement advertisement = advertisementService.findFamilyAdvertisement(advertisementId);
    familyAdvertisementInfo.setFamilyAdvertisement(advertisement);
    populateFamilyAdvertisementModel(model, familyAdvertisementInfo, member);
    return "advertisement/family/edit";
}
```

The custom annotation (`@AdvertisementExistsAndBelongsToMemberCheck`) above basically is **advised by an aspect as follows**:

```
before(long advertisementId, Member member) : advertisementBelongsToMemberControllerCheck(advertisementId, member) {
        if (!advertisementService.advertisementExistsAndBelongsToMember(advertisementId, member)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Advertisement does not belong to member!");
        }
    }
```

If an `AccessDeniedException` is thrown, then the **following controller advice exception handler kicks in**:

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public String accessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) {
    return "error/403";
}
```

Now, here is how I am **trying to test** the above controller method:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AdvertisementControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AdvertisementService advertisementService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
        when(advertisementService.advertisementExistsAndBelongsToMember(eq(111), any(Member.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        when(advertisementService.advertisementExistsAndBelongsToMember(eq(222), any(Member.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAllow() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/advertisement/family/edit/222"))//
                .andDo(print())//
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableSpringConfigured
    static class testConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public AdvertisementController advertisementController() {
            return new AdvertisementController();
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public AdvertisementService advertisementService() {
            return mock(AdvertisementService.class);
        }

    }
}
```

The test systematically fails with the **following stacktrace**:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Advertisement does not belong to member!
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:134)
    at com.bignibou.tests.controller.advertisement.AdvertisementControllerTest.shouldAllow(AdvertisementControllerTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Advertisement does not belong to member!
    at com.bignibou.aop.AdvertisementExistsAndBelongsToMemberCheckAspect.ajc$before$com_bignibou_aop_AdvertisementExistsAndBelongsToMemberCheckAspect$2$3edd453b(AdvertisementExistsAndBelongsToMemberCheckAspect.aj:34)
    at com.bignibou.controller.advertisement.AdvertisementController.editFamilyAdvertisementForm(AdvertisementController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    ... 38 more
```

I am not sure what I am getting wrong with Mockito...

Note that I did specify `/222` in the path, **indicating that my mock should return true in the aspect and allow the controller method to proceed**. However, this is not the case.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that **the type of the argument** was a `long` and I passed an `int`.

Changing to:

```
when(advertisementService.advertisementExistsAndBelongsToMember(eq(222L), any(Member.class))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
```

and:

```
@Test
public void shouldAllow() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/advertisement/family/edit/{advertisementId}", 222L))//
            .andDo(print())//
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

sorted the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is the aspect injected with the same mocked instance of AdvertisementService?

Comment: Print Object.toString() for advertisementService in the aspect code and in the @Before method and see if they match

Comment: I am going to try that but I am sure the aspect has got another unconfigured mocked instance that returns default values. How can I ensure the configured mock is used by the aspect?

Comment: Ummm.... I did a debug and both advertisementService in the @Before method and the aspect have the same hashCode indicating it is the same mocked instance... I am really puzzled....